# How to influence a bash while loop with a timed global variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, sleep

I have a `while` loop in a `bash` script which should do something different at the beginning and at every 5 second interval. Any previous loop is allowed to complete. The 5s interval is indicated by the `do_different` global variable set by the `heartbeat` function. An additional complication is that a normal `while` loop completes in an unknown amount of time (simplified with `RANDOM` in below script).
Using `cron` is not an option, neither is timing the random process.

I already unsuccessfully tried using a pipe as well as process substitution.
The whole script may be re-factored.

```
#!/bin/bash

function heartbeat {
    do_different=true
    while sleep 5s
    do
        do_different=true
    done
}

heartbeat &

while true
do
    if $do_different
    then
        echo 'Something different'
        do_different=false
        i=0
    else
        # process of random duration; not important
        r=$(( 1 + RANDOM % 3 ))
        sleep "${r}s"
        i=$((i + r))
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: No `s` suffix is needed on the argument of `sleep` if the value is seconds. POSIX describes no such suffix feature: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I am running now, based on [airfishey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214660/39845) with some corrections.

```
#!/bin/bash

t_lastdue=$(date --date='5seconds ago' +%s)

while true
do
    t_now=$(date +%s)
    t_elapsed=$((t_now - t_lastdue))
    if [ $t_elapsed -ge 5 ]
    then
        echo 'Something different'
        t_lastdue=$((t_lastdue + 5))
        i=0
    else
        # process of random duration; not important
        r=$(( 1 + RANDOM % 3 ))
        sleep "${r}s"
        i=$((i + r))
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: If being as close as possible to the 5 second interval is important you're better off using `t_lastdue=$t_now` in your if statement as `t_elapsed` could be 6 (depending on when this bash process gets serviced by the CPU scheduler). You would then be off by 1 second the next time `echo 'Something different'` runs

Comment: @airfishey: Please re-check your logic.  The current code, `t_lastdue=$((t_now - t_elapsed + 5))`, is equivalent to `t_lastdue=$((t_lastdue + 5))` (see below), which guarantees that the “different” thing happens once every five seconds (or, at least, that it averages _n_ occurrences every 5 × _n_ seconds over the long run).  By contrast, if `t_elapsed` is 6, that would mean that `t_now` = `t_lastdue` + 6, so setting `t_lastdue=$t_now` would cause precisely the schedule slippage that you’re trying to avoid.

Comment: SergeStroobandt:  Looks good.  (1) Since `t_elapsed=$((t_now - t_lastdue))`, you can reduce `t_lastdue=$((t_now - t_elapsed + 5))` to `$((t_now - (t_now - t_lastdue) + 5))` and hence to `$((t_lastdue + 5))`.  Setting `t_lastdue=$((t_lastdue + 5))`, arguably, makes it clearer that this solution tries very hard to do the “different” thing every five seconds.  (By contrast, `sleep 5s` is not guaranteed to return in exactly five seconds, so my answer (and your original attempt) can fall behind schedule (out of sync) over time.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) You should always quote shell variables (even `${r}` and `$i`; see my revised answer) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408) for a very long explanation.

Comment: @Scott: You are absolutely correct. I was thinking about it from the standpoint of we want "Something different" to happen as close as possible to 5 seconds after the last "Something different" happened. So if the second "Something different" happens at time 6 (i.e. one second late) then the next one would happen at  time 11. You're solution is closer to the OP intent. You're intent is to keep it on schedule even if the previous "Something different" was late. Thanks for clearing that up and good observation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in case it isn't obvious, the script in the question fails
because `heartbeat` runs in a child process,
and therefore cannot change shell variables in the parent shell's memory.

Here's an approach that's closer to the spirit of the OP's attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'do_different=true' USR1

heartbeat() {
    while sleep 5
    do                  # If the parent process has gone away, the child should terminate.
        kill -USR1 "$$"  ||  exit
    done
}

heartbeat &
heartbeat_pid=$!
trap 'kill "$heartbeat_pid"' 0

do_different=true

while true
do
    if "$do_different"
    then
        echo 'Something different'
        do_different=false
        i=0
    else
        # process of random duration; not important
        r=$(( 1 + RANDOM % 3 ))
        sleep "$r"
        i=$((i + r))
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

The modified `heartbeat` sends SIGUSR1 signals
to the main (parent) shell process. 
This, and SIGUSR2, are reserved for user/application use
(and should never be generated by the system). 
The `trap` command allows a shell script to catch signals. 
The `trap 'do_different=true' USR1` command tells the shell
to catch the SIGUSR1 signal (which arrives every five seconds)
and set the `do_different` flag when it occurs.

`heartbeat_pid`, obviously, is the process ID (PID)
of the `heartbeat` child process. 
The command `trap 'kill "$heartbeat_pid"' 0` defines an action to occur
upon "receipt" of the pseudo-signal 0, which refers to script exit. 
Think of this as the shell putting a sticky note on the door
saying "After you leave, remember to buy groceries on the way home." 
This action will be invoked
if the script reaches the end or executes an `exit` statement
(neither of which can happen with this script, since it is an infinite loop),
or if it is terminated by an interrupt signal
(SIGINT, which is generated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). 
This is a safety net;
the `heartbeat` process is already written to terminate
when the parent process goes away.

Comment: I saved your script under the name `test` and performed a `chmod +x` on it. Here is the error I get when trying to run it:  `./test: 5: ./test: function: not found`

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: Thanks for catching that.  The `function heartbeat {` ... syntax that you used is a bash-ism, and apparently `/bin/sh` on your system isn't bash.  I changed my answer to use the POSIX syntax.  BTW, `test` is the name of a shell builtin command, and so is a bad name for any other command.  For example, if you write a program or script called `foo` and move it to a directory that's in your search path (e.g., `/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, or `~/bin`), you can then run it by typing `foo` (rather than `./foo`).  But typing `test` will get you the builtin, and not any executable file.

Comment: I saved under name `u`, turn `RANDOM` to `$RANDOM` and luach as `bash u`, this work OK.

Comment: Note that you can use "EXIT" instead of "0" to make it more self-explanatory. Note that POSIXly it should be `kill -s USR1` though `kill -USR1` will work as well on most systems covered by U&L (and if the shell is bash)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `date` utility to get the current time in seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
lastTime=-5

while true
do
    currentTime=$(date +%s)
    elapsedTime=$((currentTime - lastTime))
    if [[ $elapsedTime -ge 5 ]]
    then
        echo 'Something different'
        lastTime=$currentTime
        i=0
    else
        # process of random duration; not important
        r=$(( 1 + RANDOM % 3 ))
        sleep ${r}s
        i=$((i + r))
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Edit: Changed `lastTime`'s initial value so that it also "does something different" at the beginning.

Comment: `lastTime=-5` is not necessary because `elapsedTime` will be the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and therefore greater than 5. Furthermore, `-gt` should read `-ge`.

Comment: Good catch on the `-gt` bug. I've edited the code with this fix. The reason to initialize `lastTime` to -5 is so that `currentTime - lastTime`  > 5 at the start as per your requirement of "should do something different at the beginning". Assume seconds since the epoch at the start of this script is 0. Without initializing `lastTime` to -5, you would have `lastTime=0` and `currentTime=0` and "something different" would not happen at the beginning.

Comment: At the beginning of the script `elapsedTime` equals `currentTime` if `lastTime` does not exist. Replacing `echo 'Something different'` by `echo $elapsedTime` returned 1436384016 over here. This is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

Comment: The correct way to initialise is `lastTime=$(date --date='5seconds ago' +%s)`. This then also allows to have `lastTime=$((currentTime - elapsedTime +5))`, which coincides with the original attempt.

Comment: Good suggestion for initializing lastTime to `$(date --date='5seconds ago' +%s)` instead of `-5`. Your suggestion is more elegant than my original `-5` implementation. As far as I know, the date utility does not return negative numbers, so both solutions should work. I may very well be wrong though

Comment: You don't need the Bash/Korn extension of `[[ ... ]]` if to test whether a variable is >= a constant. Just the POSIX syntax `if [ $elapsedTime -ge 5 ]`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using `bash` anyway, you should be using `$SECONDS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "$SECONDS" -lt 5 ] || {
      SECONDS=$((i=0))
      echo Something different
};do  sleep "$((r=(1+RANDOM)%3))"
      echo  "$((i+=r))"
done
```

From `man bash`:

> *`$SECONDS`*
>
> - This variable expands to the number of seconds since the shell was started. Assignment to this variable resets the count to the value assigned, and the expanded value becomes the value assigned plus the number of seconds since the assignment.

And here's how you can do it *and* handle *drift*:

```
S=SECONDS
while   [ "$(($S<5||(i=0*($S-=5))))" -ne 0 ] ||
        echo Something different
do      sleep "$((r=(1+RANDOM)%3))"
        echo  "$((i+=r))"
done
```

Comment: Nice code, but it does not take care of schedule slippage (see above comment by Scott).

Comment: @SergeStroobandt - Have you actually witnessed this problem he describes? If you want to handle it, you should stage a wider window. Say... every 300 iterations you compare your elapsed time to `date` or something *(of course, on a POSIX system, that's no good either because POSIX does not handle leap seconds)*, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Yes, I have. In my real-world example the heartbeat is every 1800s (half an hour) and the random process is an iteration of about 10 times 3 minutes. I created a more breve example because I did not want respondents to lose their time with this.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt - well if it's every half an hour, just schedule it with `at`. You can even ask it to send you a signal. `at now + 30m\nkill -URGENT "$$"`. You can also use `touch` on some file and sync up your alarm against the fs clock. That'll get you microseconds.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt - i implemented a means of handling *drift*.